# vue test utils how to find specific input[type="checkbox"?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, babel-jest, qcheckbox

I am using Quasar 2 Vue 3 and `@quasar/testing-e2e-jest v3.0.0-alpha.10`. I have multiple `q-checkbox` in my vue component template which I decorated with `data-test` attribute. How do I find the specific checkbox with wither `id`, `name`, and/or `data-test`? `wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]);` works just find.

Answer (score 0):

```
wrapper.find('input[id="..."]')

wrapper.find('input[value="..."]')

wrapper.find('input[data-test="..."]')
```

basically you can search with whatever attribute you want. `type` is just another HTML attribute for `input`

Comment: For some reason find doesn't work with 'input[data-test="..."]'. Says that wrapper is empty.

Comment: can you console.log the template and check whether that element HAS that attribute in the first place? you can use `console.log(wrapper.html())` for that

Comment: Panos, it was the matter of defining props inside of test description. I mean, that in my case data-test was a props with a dynamic value. So I first had to define it in test.